# python get array parameter

Tags: python, get, request

I'm comming from php where `$_GET [ 'filter' ]` on a url such as `example.com/?filter[0][field]=username&filter[0][data][type]=string&filter[0][data][value]=someusername` will return an array which can be parsed as:

```
foreach ( $_GET [ 'filter' ] as $k => $field ) {
    $fieldName = $field [$k] [ 'data' ] [ 'field' ];
    $fieldType = $field [$k] [ 'data' ] [ 'type' ];
    $fieldValue = $field [$k] [ 'data' ] [ 'value' ];
    //        do something with the values
}
```

Question is....how do I parse them in python in such way?

I cannot access `request.args.get( 'filter', None )` but I have results on `request.args.get( 'filter[0][field]', None )`

Comment: depends entirely on which of the million frameworks you use

Comment: if you're using django, please specify in your question

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

urlparse.parse_qs

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the publisher of apache mod python you can specify the arguments in your index function. Let's assume you call

```
http://yourserver/script.py?name=John&age=36
```

Then your script.py should look something like

```
def index (req, name = None, age = None):
    return "Hello %s, you are %s years old." % (name, age)
```

Same thing for both GET and POST.